# Deployed gRPC app will only uses port 5000 - need it to listen to port https://asdf.com:30000

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I am having a difficult time trying to find an answer to a seemingly simple question.

I have two issues:

1. I can get my teensy tiny gRPC app to run on port `http:localhost:5000` or `https:localhost:5001` on my dev box without issue.  When I go into `launchSettings.json` and remove http:localhost:5000 it does as expected and only listens on port 5001. Everything works as expected. My app is plagiarized directly the samples located here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/grpc) so there is no need to post any code. I'm simply following the tutorial.
2. When I deploy it to an Ubuntu 20.04 system, no matter what I have in the published app contents, it *only* listens to port 5000. On top of that, I want to listen on port 30000.  I have opened that port (as well as 5000 and 5001) in ufw.  My client will not connect. I would like to set the application URL to https://some.fqdn.com:30000, but I can't get it to listen to any other port but 5000, I can't even get to accomplishing this issue.

I am getting tired of seeing this:

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://localhost:**5000**!!

How can I get asp.net grpc to listen to a custom port on a public facing network URL?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was easy once you bumble-stumble across the millionth google search...

I added the following to my appsettings.json file:

```
    "Kestrel": {
        "EndPoints": {
            "Https": {
                "Url": "https://some.fqdn.com:30000"
            }
        },
        "EndpointDefaults": {
            "Protocols": "Http2"
        }
    }
```

Now, I just need to find an end-to-end example of how to secure the connection between the client and server and I will be golden!